Rotate - Getting the outer circle of a square array
I'd like to get the outer of a square array.
for example:the input is:
3
4 3 1
6 5 2
9 7 3

the output is
1 2 3
3 5 7
4 6 9

The original data was rotated 90 degrees to the right/clockwise.(the first number is n*n array). As my api is not the terminal or something, so I can only make the input a string split by ",". However,when I was working on my code, even I wanted to test the outer I get from the input, the browser stopped me by showing error:
No action was found on the controller 'XXX' that matches the request. 
I'm thinking there might be something wrong in my code causing that issue, can anyone help take a look?
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/sunflower/{string}")]
 public string rotate(string input)
 {
     int[] inputArr = input.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
     string message = "";
 //    string newMessage = "";
     string lastCol = "";
     int squareNum = ((int)Math.Sqrt(inputArr.Length - 1));
 //    int rotate = (inputArr[0] + 2)%4;
     for (int i = 0; i < squareNum; i++)
     {
         if (i == 0)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < squareNum; j++)
             {
                 message = message + inputArr[j + 1] + ",";
             }
         }
         else if (i != squareNum - 1)
         {
             for (int j = 1; j <= (squareNum - 2); j++)
             {
                 message = message + inputArr[squareNum * (j + 1) + 1] + ",";
                 lastCol = message + inputArr[j * squareNum + 1] + ",";
             }
         }
         else
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < squareNum; j++)
             {
                 message = message + inputArr[(squareNum - 1) * squareNum + j + 1];
             }
         }
         for (int j = lastCol.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
         {
             message = message + lastCol[j];
         }
     }
    
     return message;
 }



There are no comas in the input string you've shown. It appears to be "3\r\n4 3 1\r\n6 5 2\r\n9 7 3". Can you please show the actual string literal that gets passed to the method?

I might be misreading the question, but it's not clear to me why you're calculating the square root of the length - 1 if the first digit is the same number, and it's not clear what the expected output is.

@RufusL thanks for the feedback, my input is kind of like api.../3,4,3,1,6,5,2,9,7,3 Because I'm still learning, and according to my school professor, we can input string split by "," to set unfixed number to input.

@RufusL I guess there might be some easier way to solve the question, but mu logic is like: get the outer first into a string, as the next step is to rotate(how many 90 degree) according to the N of the n square.

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but here's an attempt at an answer. Hopefully it helps you get in the right direction.
Here's what I think I understand:

It appears that we're given a comma separated character string as input. I'm currently ignoring the initial character, but that can be dealt with if needed.
We want to create a rectangle from this string; the largest one that will hold all the items
We want to then rotate the perimeter of the rectangle some number of times.

In order to solve this, I would:

Create a method that takes in an int representing the number of items and returns a size representing the largest rectangle that can hold said number of items.
Create a method that takes in a string (our comma-separated list of chars) and returns a char[,] representing the rectangle of characters.
Create a method that takes in a char[,] and returns a new char[,] with the perimeter rotated one rotation, where a rotation is when the first character is now in second column, the second in third, etc., until we get to the end of the row, where the last character becomes the last character of the next row, and when we get down to the last row, each character moves to the left until we get to the first column, where the first character in the last row becomes the first character in the previous row.
And finally we need a method that will print out a chr[,] to the screen

Here's a sample implementation:
Create a method that takes in an int representing the number of items and returns a size representing the largest rectangle that can hold said number of items:
static Size GetMaxRectSize(int numItems)
{
    // Start with a line numItems long
    var rect = new Size(1, numItems);

    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(numItems); i++)
    {
        if (numItems % i == 0)
        {
            rect.Width = i;
            rect.Height = numItems / i;
        }
    }

    return rect;
}

Create a method that takes in a string (our comma-separated list of chars) and returns a char[,] representing the rectangle of characters
static char[,] GetRect(string input)
{
    List<char> inputArr = input
        .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(i => i[0])
        .ToList();

    var size = GetMaxRectSize(inputArr.Count);

    char[,] rect = new char[size.Height, size.Width];

    for (int row = 0; row < size.Height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size.Width; col++)
        {
            rect[row, col] = inputArr[row * size.Width + col];
        }
    }

    return rect;
}

Create a method that takes in a char[,] and returns a new char[,] with the perimeter rotated one rotation
static char[,] RotatePerimeter(char[,] input)
{
    var rowCount = input.GetLength(0);
    char[,] rotated = new char[rowCount, rowCount];

    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        if (row == 0)
        {
            rotated[0, 0] = input[1, 0];

            for (int col = 0; col < rowCount - 1; col++)
            {
                rotated[row, col + 1] = input[row, col];
            }
        }
        else if (row == rowCount - 1)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < rowCount - 1; col++)
            {
                rotated[row, col] = input[row, col + 1];
            }

            rotated[row, rowCount - 1] = input[row - 1, rowCount - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            rotated[row, 0] = input[row + 1, 0];
            for (int col = 1; col < rowCount - 1; col++)
            {
                rotated[row, col] = input[row, col];
            }
            rotated[row, rowCount - 1] = input[row - 1, rowCount - 1];
        }
    }

    return rotated;
}

Create a method that will print out a chr[,] to the screen
void PrintRect(char[,] rect)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rect.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < rect.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            Console.Write(rect[row, col]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

Then in usage it would look something like:
using System.Drawing;

var rect = GetRect("4,3,1,6,5,2,9,7,3");
PrintRect(rect);

while(true)
{
    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key for next rotation...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
    rect = RotatePerimeter(rect);
    PrintRect(rect);
}

To get results like what you show above (for 90 degree rotation), we need to rotate it times:


Awesome!!!  That's actually more than what I need. Thanks soooooo much for the details and step-by step explanation. Really useful and helpful. Also my bad, the rotation(90) occurs based on each side of the square. For example: the first row 4,3,1 will become the last column 4,3,1 after one rotation(right) or the first column 1,3,4 after left rotation.
